# Identifying a 3-Terminal Component (probably some sort of magnetic device?)

Tags: components, identification, radio

I am trying to identify this component from a circa 70s AM/FM radio.  It was attached to a flip clock, which makes me think that it is a magnetic device responsible for the "flipping" action of the clock.

[image]

[image]

The three terminals are labeled N.O., COM, and N.C., in that order.  Google search isn't being my friend right now, and is giving results which seem completely unrelated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a microswitch.  The red button on the edge throws the switch when something presses it.  The contacts are labelled Normally Open, Normally Closed, and Common.

Comment: This is correct. Perhaps there was a weight in the clock, that would activate the microswitch when it was "flipped"?

Comment: @bitsmack I was confused because I did not find any mechanical parts near the switch, other than some unrelated gears which appeared to set the ratio of minutes to hours.  Perhaps someone tinkered with the clock before I received it?